# Android Listview entry duplication

Tags: android, listview, duplicates

Am fairly new to android programming i have a Listview whose values are being populated in my code but whenever there is an orientation change, or resume the list entries are being repopulated (leading to duplication of entries) how do i resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as you requested , you can see a sample Adapter which have used ViewHolder for a ListView :

```
public class AllCustomerListCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Cursor c;                       // Passed in cursor
private Activity context;


public CustomAdapter(Activity context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.c = c;
    this.context = context;

    c.moveToFirst();
}

static class ViewHolder 
{
    public TextView rowView1;
    public TextView rowView2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    c.moveToPosition(position);


    if (rowView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rowView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem1);
        holder.rowView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtListItem2);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    holder.rowView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_VIEW1)));
    holder.rowView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_VIEW2)));


return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arash It worked but i also noticed that if you define your values before passing it to the listview adapter you also get the same effect. I was actually using an arraylist without checking if it contained any values .So the arraylist was being populated from the server everytime and in turn getview of the adapter was called to populate rows . Thanks all

Comment: @user2894222 : good to hear that and if this is helpful to you please mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

For API higher than 13 in `manifest.xml` in your activity just add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and for lower APIs just `android:configChanges="orientation"`

> If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the
>   minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also
>   declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a
>   device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

Comment: I was looking to fix a similar issue, but for a RecyclerView. This line solved the problem for me. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute `android:configChanges` with the value `orientation` on your activity definition, on manifest file, to prevent recreating the activity on orientation changes.

```
<Activity
...
...
android:configChanges="orientation"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView has a Adapter for fill data in it.
i think you used it already in your code?
so you have to  clear data in adapter before set it to the list view to avoid duplicated items.
i had same problem and by using it solved...
if you put your code also i mention it for you...

Comment: In ListView you don't have to clear data before setting Adapter everytime!your answer is a bit confusing and unclear.repeating items in ListView are because of Recycling behavior of ListViews which you can prevent it by holders.and dear Hossein i think your answer should be a comment

Comment: @Arash how do i use holders please explain

Comment: @user2894222 : see my example

Answer (score 0):

This is an intended behavior in android, when you change orientation , it will start a new activity
You can make use of [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When
>   a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down
>   and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the
>   activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is
>   called.

Add it to you `manifest.xml` file like this `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Comment: okay i do understand that everytime you change orientation oncreate method is called but i still want to prevent duplication of entries because i populate the list in my code. How do i check if the list has already been populated